# GTA V Cannot be Backup up via Steam?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v

I have GTA V on Steam (legitimate copy), and I want to make a simple backup. When I go to Grand Theft Auto V (right click), and then "Backup Game Files", I get this error:

[image]

Currently, GTA V is not updating and neither are any other games. No games in my Steam library have any activity on them when this message is showing up. Why could this be?

Comment: Please try restarting Steam, that could trigger any pending updates. Meanwhile I will search for a solution

Comment: @Mano thanks, but I'm going to sleep now (2AM with school tomorrow :') ) but I will try your suggestion tomorrow,

Comment: I can't find an actual source to confirm it, but read a rumor that Steam cannot backup some games which use third-party DRM. GTA V is one of those games as noted on the [PCGamingWiki](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_V) page (Arxan Anti-Tamper DRM).